# Load a local webpage into the webbrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I am trying to simply add a webbrowser control to a window and then have it open up a page. I tried a web URL as well as a local HTML file to no avail. Here is my code:

namespace qTab1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream source = new FileStream("index.html", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        webBrowser1.DocumentStream = source;
        //// When the form loads, open this web page.
        //webBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com");
    }

    private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Set text while the page has not yet loaded.
        this.Text = "Navigating";
    }

    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender,
        WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Better use the e parameter to get the url.
        // ... This makes the method more generic and reusable.
        this.Text = e.Url.ToString() + " loaded";
    }
}
```

}

This is my project at the moment:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The reason this happens is that when you press **Debug** or build your project any other way the root directory is the directory of the executable (so it would be - **./bin/Debug**), not the directory of the project.

To fix this, you can do the following:

1. Right click the html file, click **Properties** and set the variable "**Copy to output directory**" to **Copy always**. That way, the html file will get copied with your executable.
2. Now you have to load the local file into the WebBrowser control. The following should work :

   webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("file:///" + Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/index.html");

Comment: All of what you said made sense but I am still getting a blank page with nothing loading after your suggestions.

Comment: I thought I was wrong in something. Just made a quick check (following the same steps I've written) and everything seems fine. 

Please, check your **./bin/Debug** folder. Does it contain the index.html?